# Better way to move bring DataGridRows from one DataGridView to another

Tags: c#

The title might be slightly misleading, but I can't quite think how to describe this better in just a few words unfortunately, so apologies if it's not fitting.

Anyway, I am querying a SQL table containing orders placed.

I store all orders queried results in a `List` and to display to the user I tranform it into a `DataTable` and use it as the `DataSource` of a `DataGridView`, which works just fine. Effectively this first `DataGridView` can be considered to contain all orders.

I then have a second `DataGridView` which contains orders that belong to the employee running the application. Again there's a `List` in the back end and a `DataGridView` to display this to the user.

Now I'd like to allow the user to bring orders that would not normally be in his personal `DataGridView` into it. The idea is the user selects orders (rows) from the "all orders" `DataGridView` and when he clicks a button those get added to the "users orders" `DataGridView`.

However, because in the back end there is a `List` (and the `DataGridView` contains a `DataSource` so I can't just add rows to it), I can't add directly from one DataGridView to the other.

I have the following **working** code, but I think it can be simplified and am just after some suggestions:

```
foreach (var row in dgvAllTenants.SelectedRows.Cast<DataGridViewRow>().Where(row => _myTenants.Count(x => x.TenantId.ToString() == row.Cells["TenantId"].Value.ToString()) == 0))
{
    _myTenants.Add(_allTenants.Where(x => x.TenantId.ToString() == row.Cells["TenantID"].Value.ToString()).ToList()[0]);
}

dgvMyTenants.DataSource = _myTenants.ToDataTable();
```

Comment: It's been awhile since I've messed with datagridview, but if I recall, you can just add items to the underlying datasource and they magically appear. You can also get the data item underlying a row. So, can you grab the selected rows, get the DataItems, and just pop it into the List that is the backing of the grid you want to add to? (edit: oh, wait, you transformed the list to a data table, maybe can't do this)

Comment: so out of curiosity, why change the List to DataTable to bind instead of using object data source?

Comment: @Nikki, because I'm using a List<Dynamic> and as such there will be no columns unless I do this.